# Ctrl+Z Signal handling in C

Tags: c, macos, signals

I am writing a simple shell in C.

However, I found that my program cannot properly handle the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> signal. My program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
void interpreter() {
char input[256];
int i;
char dir[PATH_MAX+1];
char *argv[256];
int argc = 0;
char *token;
if (getcwd(dir, PATH_MAX+1) == NULL) {
    //error occured
    exit(0);
}
printf("[shell:%s]$ ", dir);
fgets(input,256,stdin);
if (strlen(input) == 0) {
    exit(0);
}
input[strlen(input)-1] = 0;
if (strcmp(input,"") == 0) {
    return;
}
token = strtok(input, " ");
while(token && argc < 255) {
    argv[argc++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
argv[argc] = 0;
    pid_t forknum = fork();
    if (forknum != 0) {
        int status;
        waitpid(forknum, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } else {
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
        setenv("PATH","/bin:/usr/bin:.",1);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        if (errno == ENOENT) {
            printf("%s: command not found\n", argv[0]);
        } else {
            printf("%s: unknown error\n", argv[0]);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() {
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
while(1) {
    interpreter();
}
}
```

I have ignored above signals in the main process.

When I start `cat(1)` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the next line of input will still be captured by the `cat(1)` program rather than my main process. It means that my main process will do nothing but if I wake up the `cat(1)` program, it will output what I typed immediately. All things go back to normal after this.

I can't figure out how to resolve this. I am still not sure if I have stated it clearly.

Comment: This is very unclear: *the next line of input will still go to cat rather than my main*...

Comment: Let me provide a example. After the cat program is suspended, I type "cat", another cat is supposed to be started but nothing happens. If I wake up the previous cat program, it will immediately output "cat".

Comment: Can you post the full code, the expected behavior, and the behavior you're getting?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I have posted the full code.     Input : "cat""ctrl-d""cat", expected behavior: a cat started then suspended, a new cat started, behavior now: a cat started then suspended.

Comment: In what way are you restarting the cat process? What are you expecting the shell process to do when you suspend the foreground process?

Comment: @hexturtle Actually I have added a lot of code to add new functions such as waking up suspended process. As far as I am concerned, it will just suspend that child process and the main process will return from waitpit and is able to tokenlize and run next line of command

Comment: Nitpick: there's no such thing as the `Ctrl-Z` signal. `Ctrl-Z` is just a common keyboard combination that makes the terminal device driver send `SIGTSTP` to the foreground process group; but it can be changed as part of the terminal settings (see [`tcsetattr(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Even though this is tagged Linux, I'll go out on a limb and say that you are running this on OS X.

When compiled on Linux, the problem is not there, but on Mac it happens exactly as you described. It looks like a bug in OS X: because both the shell process and `cat(1)` are on the same process group (since you don't explicitly change group membership), it seems like OS X makes the mistake of feeding the next input line to the `fgets(3)` call that is asleep in the `cat(1)` process, so you end up losing that line of input from the shell process (because it is consumed by the sleeping `cat(1)`).

The reason this doesn't happen with bash is because bash supports job control, and as such processes are put in separate process groups (in particular, bash chooses the first process of a process pipeline as the process group leader). So when you do the same thing on bash, each invocation of `cat(1)` ends up putting it in a separate process group (and then the shell controls which process group is in the foreground with `tcsetpgrp(3)`). So, at any time, it is clear which process group has control over terminal input; the moment you suspend `cat(1)` in bash, the foreground process group is changed to bash again and input is read successfully.

If you do the same as bash in your shell, it will work in Linux, OS/X, and basically any other UNIX variant (and it is how other shells do it too).

In fact, if you want your shell to have job support, you'll have to do this sooner or later (learn about process groups, sessions, `tcsetpgrp(3)`, `setpgid(2)`, etc.).

So, in short, do the right thing if you want job support and wrap the forked process in a new process group:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void interpreter() {
    char input[256];
    char dir[PATH_MAX+1];
    char *argv[256];
    int argc = 0;
    char *token;
    if (getcwd(dir, PATH_MAX+1) == NULL) {
        //error occured
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("[shell:%s]$ ", dir);
    fgets(input,256,stdin);

    if (strlen(input) == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    input[strlen(input)-1] = 0;
    if (strcmp(input,"") == 0) {
        return;
    }
    token = strtok(input, " ");
    while(token && argc < 255) {
        argv[argc++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    argv[argc] = 0;
    pid_t forknum = fork();
    if (forknum != 0) {
        setpgid(forknum, forknum);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, forknum);
        tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, forknum);
        int status;
        waitpid(forknum, &status, WUNTRACED);
        tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, getpid());
        tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpid());
    } else {
        setpgid(0, getpid());
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
        setenv("PATH","/bin:/usr/bin:.",1);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        if (errno == ENOENT) {
            printf("%s: command not found\n", argv[0]);
        } else {
            printf("%s: unknown error\n", argv[0]);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
    while(1) {
        interpreter();
    }
}
```

(Although, admittedly, it is unfortunate that OS X does such a poor job in this situation - you really shouldn't *have* to do this).

The changes are just inside the process-specific code: both the child and the parent call `setpgid(2)` to make sure that the newborn process is indeed in a single process group before either the parent of the process itself assumes that this is already true (this pattern is recommended in *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment*); the `tcsetpgrp(3)` call must be invoked by the parent.

Of course, this is far from complete, you then need to code the necessary functions to bring a job back to the foreground, list jobs, etc. But the code above works with your test scenario nonetheless.

Nitpick: you should be using [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead of the deprecated, unreliable and platform-dependent `signal(3)`, but it's a minor issue here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @vincentzhou Glad I could help. Best of luck with your project :)

Comment: Your code works well. However, I have added pipes and job control functions to my program which made things rather complicated. For command "A|B|C", my main process will fork children in a loop and then wait for them. As far as I am concerned, all process of a single line of command should belong to one group and I set the group id to the first guy. For tcsetgrp, I am not sure  which process should I bind stdout to. For now, the previous problem seems to be solved,but when I wake a suspended program, the error "stdin: Interrupted system call" appears.

Comment: @vincentzhou Yes, all processes in a pipeline should share the same group. You should pass the process group ID to `tcsetpgrp(3)`; this is the same as the PID of the group leader (which you mentioned is the first process in the pipeline). About the interrupted syscall error: you need to either start using `sigaction(2)` and set the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction` (see `man 7 signal` for more info.), or explicitly test for `errno == EINTR` in your code and call the read function again. If this all looks very complicated to you, I suggest posting another question.

Comment: Actually the cat program outputs the error message and I cannot ask cat to read again. I have tried the first method but do not work. But it seems the built-in terminal of osx also has this bug.